# importing xml files into spring batch job context file

Tags: xml, eclipse, spring, batch-processing

I have an xml context file for a spring batch job with following resource import

```
 <import resource="classpath:/topsecret.xml" />
```

the imported class (topsecret.xml) looks like so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
<bean id="deleteTable" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg type="String" value="DELETE FROM ${schema}.TABLE" />
</bean>
```

when I reference the bean id in my job context file and hover the mouse over it in eclipse, it doesn't bring a clickable link to the bean in the imported resource. is this indicative of a failure or is this something that is most likely linked at run time?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using [STS](http://spring.io/tools) I don't think out-of-the-box Eclipse has this feature.
If you are using STS (which I recommend), then you need to do the following:

- Right click on your Spring project (it has to be a Spring project)
- Go to "Spring" option, then "Beans Support"
- In the Tab called "Config Files", add your job context xml file and your `topsecret.xml` file
- In the same page, make sure you check "Enable support for  element in configuration files"
- Click Ok and try again with your beans.